# PHP Trim both sides + max 1 between between chars

Tags: php, string

In PHP you can use trim(...) function to trim vertical tabs, spaces and more by default second argument. I want to both trim in the ends everything, but I also if there are more than one instance of illegal characters between 2 legal, chop those off to 1.

Examples:

```
[V][S]h[V][V][S]ello[V] --> h[V]ello
[V][S]h[V][V][S]el[S][V][V]lo[V] --> h[V]el[S]lo
[V][S]hell[V]o[V] --> hell[V]o
```

What's the most efficient way to do this in PHP?

Comment: @JohnConde If so, what are the default illegal chars for the trim method?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/trim for the defaults.

Comment: @JohnConde " \t\n\r\0\x0B" What's the best regex for that?

Comment: @Jonathan $r = "/[^ \t\n\r\0\x0B][ \t\n\r\0\x0B]+[^ \t\n\r\0\x0B]/g"; return trim(preg_replace($r, "", $s)); Why doesn't that work?

Comment: @Jonathan There's no errors on r101

Comment: @JohnConde It throws errors when I use preg_replace with null bytes???